# properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDateSinged"] will show the date minus one hour

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver, office-365-developer, date

I have the following code inside my remote event receiver inside a SharePoint online team site, the remote event receiver is deployed inside azure web service:-

```
if (i["ProjectDateSinged"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties.ContainsKey("ProjectDateSinged") && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDateSinged"] != null)
{
DateTime currentpds = (DateTime)(i["ProjectDateSinged"]);
DateTime afterpds   = (DateTime.Parse(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString()));
if (currentpds.Date != afterpds.Date)
    errormessage = errormessage + "You are not authorized to update DateSigned. ";
}
```

the code is to prevent users from updating a field named ProjectDateSinged... but currently the code is failing because i am getting the same date in different amounts. for example if i have an item with `ProjectDateSinged = 15 July 2020`, then the `(DateTime)(i["ProjectDateSinged"])` will be equal to `15/07/2020 00:00:00` which is correct, while the `(DateTime.Parse(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString()))` will be equal to `14/07/2020 23:00:00` which is one hour before the correct value, so the validation will always fail.. any advice on how i can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Compare after converting both to UTC.

Comment: @SOURAVMUKHERJEE i tried to do so , but on some values the comparison will also fail

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores dates in UTC format. The DateTime returned by `AfterProperties["ProjectDateSinged"]` is in UTC format. You will need to convert the `DateTime afterpds` to the same format that you are using for `DateTime currentpds` and then compare the dates.